# box bottom is valid

Tags: logic

This question was posted to me:

What property of our relation $R$ between worlds must be true if we know that the following formula is valid?

$\square \bot$

I am completely stumped and have no idea what to do. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Write out what $\square\bot$ means semantically.

Comment: I only know that (maybe its wrong, even) it means for all possible scenarios, $\square$ means for all scenario it is true. So does it mean $\bot$ is always true?

Comment: Seeing as your description doesn't involve $R$ or any relation, you should suspect something is wrong/missing. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic#Semantics) has a reasonable introduction to the semantics of modal logic, though you will likely need to find additional resources. As far as I can tell, the issue isn't that you don't know what to do, but that you don't know what the question is even asking.

Comment: @DerekElkins $R$ is the accessibility relation between worlds, so the question is fine.

Answer (score 1):

$\bot$ is false in every world. For any formula $\varphi$, the formula $\Box\,\varphi$ is true in a world if $\varphi$ is true in every successor of that world. A formula is *valid* if it is true in every world.

So, $\Box\,\bot$ being valid means that $\bot$ is true in every successor of every world. But $\bot$ can't be true in any successor. The only way that these two things can be true is _________.

An alternative way to think about this is to consider that $\Box\,\varphi$ is equivalent to $\neg\Diamond\,\neg\varphi$.